# VBScript executing Microsoft Excel DCOM remotely failing

Tags: windows, service, cmd, vbscript, components

VBscript creates the Microsoft excel object and converts the file to a TSV. This VBScript is executed over the web, it was working for the last year up until now, the DCOM settings shown below;

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQovK.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaDRB.jpg)

Security has full rights on a user group
Identity is set to a fixed user and password

The issue is this only works when an admin user is logged onto the server, I need help getting this to work without any user signed in. Preferably without auto logging in a user on restart.

Any suggestions would help here.

This is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64 bit,
I've tried adding 'Everyone' with full rights to the Security on the DCOM still requires someone on the server.
I have edited settings in both 32 bit and 64 bit in Component Services.
I suspect a particular service runs when I remote in which this process seems to rely on.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application", "localhost")
```

Comment: How the script failing? Any errors?

Comment: @montonero No errors, but the script hangs and remains open. I can see this when i remote in and see the script running in Task Manager but doing nothing.